# How to format command output in windbg script?

Tags: windbg

Does someone here know how to format the output of windbg command in its script?
Can windbg support regular expression?

Is there some tutorial?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You can look at the comments in the debugger script linked to in this [blog post](http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2012/12/dumping-method-descriptor-for.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can run your commands against the command line version of WinDbg, cdb.exe and format the output using perl or python or other script. You do need to tell us what you want to achieve, you can improve the output by turning on DML markup

```
.dml_start
```

also you can set this as a preference so it remembers it for every session:

```
.prefer_dml 1
```

The above turns on hyperlinks that execute commands but it doesn't change the formatting.